# Simple captcha audio settings in java

Tags: java, simplecaptcha

I have a form in which I have implemented  [Simple captcha](http://simplecaptcha.sourceforge.net/) every thing is working fine but I want audio captcha to be played when users click on play button. In my case audio gets played default on page load.

Below is my code for audio captcha

```
public class MyAudioCaptcha extends AudioCaptchaServlet {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {

        MyTextProducer myTextProducer  = (MyTextProducer) req.getSession().getAttribute("myTextProducer");
        if(myTextProducer == null){
            myTextProducer = new MyTextProducer();

        }
        AudioCaptcha ac = new AudioCaptcha.Builder().
                addAnswer(myTextProducer).
                addNoise().
                build(); // Required

                CaptchaServletUtil.writeAudio(resp, ac.getChallenge());
                req.getSession().setAttribute("audioCaptcha", ac);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Util.AppendExceptionToLog(e);
    }

  }
}
```

JSP code:

```
   <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            reloadCaptcha();
        });
      function reloadCaptcha(){
        var d = new Date();
        $.ajax({
          url:"captcha.jsp",
          type :"POST",
          async:true,
          data: { 
            'action':  'generateCaptcha' ,
          },
        success:function(response){
           $("#captcha_image").attr("src", "../../simpleCaptcha.png?"+d.getTime());
           $("#captcha_audio").attr("src", "../../audio.wav?"+d.getTime());

         },
     });    

    }
   </script>
<body>
    <td>
     <div class="inputfield" style="margin-left: 10px;">
        <img  id="captcha_image" /> 
        <img  src="../../images/reload.jpg" onclick="reloadCaptcha()" style="cursor: pointer;" alt="reload"width="30" height="30"/>
    </div>
   </td>
   <td>
        <audio controls autoplay  id="captcha_audio" autoplay = "false"></audio>
   </td>
</body>
```

Is there any configurable in above code so that audio do not play on page load, to be played only if user click on audio captcha [image]

Comment: Have you checked if it's not your browser which autoplay the given media ? [How to stop auto playing media](http://www.howtogeek.com/227669/how-to-stop-auto-playing-html5-videos-in-your-web-browser/)

Comment: Can You add your view (JSP, HTML or whatever) where your audio captcha is getting written?

Comment: @TahirHussainMir I have added jsp code

Comment: you are setting both `autoplay` and `autoplay = false`, please remove the duplicate attribute and also the spaces around the `=` sign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You configued the `autoplay` and `autoplay = "false"` in the `<audio>` tag, you should remove them.

The autoplay attribute is a boolean attribute.

When present, the audio will automatically start playing as soon as it can do so without stopping.

-- [From w3cschool](http://www.w3schools.com/Tags/att_audio_autoplay.asp)

Comment: I removed complete autoplay and it is working fine. Thanks `<audio controls id = "captcha_audio"></audio>`